# Is it possible to change the order of entries or posts on the homepage?

Tags: entries, structure

I need to change the order of the posts / entries on our homepage - is there a way of doing that?

Comment: It depends on how they're output. 

- If they are included via an entries field on the homepage entry, then you can rearrange their relations
- If they're just included in the template you should consider including them via a relation field or defining the order in a structure. Then they'll have the handle mentioned in the answer

Comment: I would recommend adding a screenshot of what your entries look like currently, as there are many possibilities of how this would occur

Answer (score 0):

You can just drag & drop the entries in the grid

[image]

Comment: Only if it's a Structure though